# How to store and retrieve an object from Gson in android?

Tags: android, gson, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

In my activity, the user has an array of images he picks, and then I want to store them in preferences. Then the user leaves the activity, and comes back, I want those images still loaded into an **ImageView**. I'm trying to use Gson to accomplish this, but am having trouble and can't see what I'm doing wrong. 
Hoping external insight may help me with this obvious answer I'm just not seeing.

Thank you.

Here is my code so far.

```
private void savePreferencesForImages(String key, ArrayList<Image> imageList)
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(imageList);
        editor.putString(key,json);
        editor.commit();
    }


//Storing Local data.
private void loadPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String gsonString = sharedPreferences.getString("userImages", "");
    ArrayList<Image> images = gson.fromJson(gsonString, Image.class);//Ask StackOverflow tomorrow.
}
```

Comment: `Image.class` cannot be loaded into an `ArrayList<Image>` is that your problem?

Comment: @cricket_007 well its given me three suggestions. I do have an error message that pops up on that line. But, im not sure which line will ensure I have an ArrayList called images, that is filled with the user's images. 

either:

1)change variable 'images' type to the image library.

2)Migrate 'images' type to Image library

3)Make 'fromJson' return java.util.ArrayList

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think its a duplicate answer. That;s converting a Json object to ArrayList.

Comment: And that is what the code you have is attempting to do, no? `fromJson` == "converting a JSON object to ArrayList"?

Comment: Well, I'm not converting anything. I'm saving an arrayList of objects into preferences. And then, retrieving the same ArrayList of objects from preferences. I just want to save an arrayList and retrieve an arrayList in local storage. Not trying to do any converting. Maybe theres a better way to do it that I am not aware of?

Comment: Okay, so the answer you accepted was just what the duplicate said to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the part of retrieving the data you will need a type that deserialize the String into a List of Images...

like:

```
private void loadPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Image>>() {}.getType();
    String gsonString = sharedPreferences.getString("userImages", "");
    List<Image> images = gson.fromJson(gsonString, type);
}
```

Comment: What would be "reader" in: List<Image> images = gson.fromJson(reader, type);

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is save the images individually and then load them into an ArrayList upon retrieval.

```
private void savePreferencesForImages(ArrayList<Image> imageList)
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    int imgKey = 0;
    for (Image img: imageList) {
        String json = gson.toJson(imageList);
        editor.putString("" + imgKey,json);
        editor.commit();
        imgKey++;
    }
}


private ArrayList<Image> loadPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Map<String, ?> allPrefs = sharedPreferences.getAll();
    String gsonString = sharedPreferences.getString("userImages", "");
    ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
    if (!allPrefs.isEmpty()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allPrefs.entrySet()) {
            String json = entry.getValue().toString();
            Image temp = gson.fromJson(json, Image.class);
            images.add(temp);
        }
    }
    return images;
}
```

This is potentially the most over-complicated way to go about this but it is the first thing I could think of. You could also just make your own ImageManager class or something and emulate the behavior of an ArrayList, with a getImage(key) method and so on. This would eliminate the complications that are brought about when trying to save an ArrayList.

Comment: Yeah i ran into that way as well (and thank you for the solution). So, i used the Gson library, which allows you to put complex data types into shared preferences with a few lines of codes. I highly recommend using it if you ever need to.